# material texture won't show up

Tags: texturing, materials

In the viewport, I can't see the texture I just applied to the object.

[image]

Comment: That's done it. Thank you.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett you should consider writing an actual answer for the OP to accept. Answers left as comments are not searchable and not much help for *future users.*

Comment: Ok. I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

You are in solid preview mode. If you look, there are 4 little circles in the top-right of your viewport that represent the different preview modes (From left to right - Wireframe, Solid, Material Preview, Rendered Preview) - to view your textures, pick one of the two rightmost ones (Material Preview, or Rendered Preview). You can also press Z in the viewport and pick the correct preview mode from the pie menu that appears.